# Histogram counting apostrophes as a word

Tags: haskell

I am to create a histogram which counts the top 20 most common words, excluding the top 20 in the world. This is the result i get below:

```
import Data.List(sort, group, sortBy)
toWordList = words
countCommonWords wordList = length (filter isCommon wordList)
  where isCommon word = elem word commonWords

dropCommonWords wordList = filter isUncommon wordList
  where isUncommon w = notElem w commonWords


commonWords = ["the","and","have","not","as","be","a","I","on", "you","to","in","it","with","do","of","that","for","he","at"]
countWords wordList = map (\w -> (head w, length w)) $group $ sort wordList
compareTuples (w1, n1) (w2, n2) = if n1 < n2 then LT else if n1> n2 then GT else EQ

sortWords wordList = reverse $ sortBy compareTuples wordList

toAsteriskBar x = (replicate (snd x) '*') ++ " -> " ++ (fst x) ++ "\n"
makeHistogram wordList = concat $ map toAsteriskBar (take 20 wordList)


--Do word list

text = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way--in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only. there were a king with a large jaw and a queen with a plain face, on the throne of England; there were a king with a large jaw and a queen with a fair face, on the throne of France. In both countries it was clearer than crystal to the lords of the State preserves of loaves and fishes, that things in general were settled for ever of."

main = do
  let wordlist = toWordList text
  putStrLn "Report:"
  putStrLn ("\t" ++ (show $ length wordlist) ++ " words")
  putStrLn ("\t" ++ (show $ countCommonWords wordlist) ++ " common words")
  putStrLn "\nHistogram of the most frequent words (excluding common words):\n"
  putStr $ makeHistogram $ sortWords $ countWords $ dropCommonWords  $ wordlist
```

Result:

```
Report:
    186 words
    71 common words
Histogram of the most frequent words (excluding common words):
************ -> was
***** -> were
**** -> we
** -> us,
** -> times,
** -> throne
** -> there
** -> season
** -> queen
** -> large
** -> king
** -> jaw
** -> its
** -> had
** -> going
** -> face,
** -> epoch
** -> direct
** -> before
** -> all
```

Does anybody know why the counter is counting any word with an apostrophe attached eg. `us,` as a whole word?

Comment: why would it not? `words` only splits the string on whitespace, a comma is not whitespace.

Comment: how would i go about changing this? I thought adding

```dropNonLetters wordList = filter (\x -> x `elem` (' ':['a'..'z'])) wordList```
would make a difference but it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Brief**

```
toWordList = words
```

This is the function I'd modify to sanitize your words.  For example, `toWordList = map (filter isAlpha) . words` so you get only those characters in words that are alphabetical instead of all blocks of characters that are divided by spaces (which is what `words` does).  EDIT: `isAlpha` is from the `Data.Char` module which you'd need to import. Edited the above snippet to add `map` too.

**Epilog**

Moving forward, I'm just going to make some code comments because why not.

```
import Data.List(sort, group, sortBy)
```

Yay, using pre-existing code.  You will probably also want `comparing` from `Data.Ord`.

```
countCommonWords wordList = length (filter isCommon wordList)
  where isCommon word = elem word commonWords

dropCommonWords wordList = filter isUncommon wordList
  where isUncommon w = notElem w commonWords
```

These operations are `O(n * m) where`n`is the length of wordList and`m`is the length of`commonWords`.  You could make this faster by using a Set if you desire.

```
commonWords = ["the","and","have","not","as","be","a","I"
              ,"on","you","to","in","it","with","do","of","that"
              ,"for","he","at"]

countWords wordList = map (\w -> (head w, length w)) $ group $ sort wordList
```

A similar performance comment here.  A common method is to use `Data.Map.insertWith` to keep a counter for each word.

```
compareTuples (w1, n1) (w2, n2) = if n1 < n2 then LT else if n1> n2 then GT else EQ
```

This is more easily spelled `compareTuples = comparing fst`

Comment: problem is I have to get the exact result of:
```Report:
185 words
73 common words
Histogram of the most frequent words (excluding common words):
************ -> was
***** -> were
**** -> we
** -> us
** -> times
** -> throne
** -> there
** -> season
** -> queen
** -> period
** -> large
** -> king
** -> jaw
** -> its
** -> had
** -> going
** -> face
** -> epoch
** -> direct
** -> before```

Without altering any of the code below ```main= do```

Comment: Why is that a problem?